# List of things that are illegal to sell online?

Tags: united-states, internet, business

I'm looking for a list of products/things/services that are illegal to sell online. Preferably not just things that are illegal to sell in person as well.

For instance, I believe it is illegal to sell/ship pets online?

Comment: Ebay's listing looks pretty comprehensive: http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/items-ov.html

Comment: @Mark I think those are things that is a mixture of their preferences and what is legal. I